# Go - How to convert binary string as text to binary bytes?

Tags: go, type-conversion

I have a **text** dump file with `string`s like this one:

```
x\x9cK\xb42\xb5\xaa.\xb6\xb2\xb0R\xcaK-\x09J\xccKOU
```

I need to convert them to `[]byte`.

Can someone please suggest how this can be done in Go?
The `python` equivalent is `decode('string_escape')`.

Comment: and the -1 is because...?

Comment: Your question isn't actually unsuitable, but you probably got a minus 1 because we like people to show what they have tried, what results they got and what results they were expecting. As it stands it sounds a bit like "I need to do x", "please do x for me as I can't be bothered to search myself" .... live and learn :)

Comment: See [How to Ask - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). It's not obvious that you did any homework. That's my guess as to why you were down voted.

Comment: @ChrisFarmiloe - I guess I should have elaborated on what I've done so far. I tried about every single function in `hex` and `strconv` to parse the string, plus doing some manual conversion, without success. As I stated, in Python, you need a simple decode action, so I assumed such a conversion/decode exists in Go as well. I burned a day trying to solve this, so it was far from "please do this for me". I just expected a simple conversion function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it.  Note this isn't a complete decode of the python `string_escape` format, but may be sufficient given the example you've given.

[playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/MTjQ97_-bl)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "regexp"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    b := []byte(`x\x9cK\xb42\xb5\xaa.\xb6\xb2\xb0R\xcaK-\x09J\xccKOU`)
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`\\x([0-9a-fA-F]{2})`)
    r := re.ReplaceAllFunc(b, func(in []byte) []byte {
        i, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(in[2:]), 16, 64)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to convert hex: %s", err)
        }
        return []byte{byte(i)}
    })
    fmt.Println(r)
    fmt.Println(string(r))
}
```

I did have the idea of using the `json` decoder, but unfortunately it doesn't understand the `\xYY` syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been spending the whole day trying to figure out how to do that. Still I don't get why I receive -1 for the question. Oh well, whatever...

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you might approach write a little parser (if you needed to support other esc things in the future):

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/hex"
)

func decode(bs string) ([]byte,error) {
    in := []byte(bs)
    res := make([]byte,0)
    esc := false
    for i := 0; i<len(in); i++ {
        switch {
        case in[i] == '\\':
            esc = true
            continue
        case esc:
            switch {
            case in[i] == 'x':
                b,err := hex.DecodeString(string(in[i+1:i+3]))
                if err != nil {
                    return nil,err
                }
                res = append(res, b...)
                i = i+2
            default:
                res = append(res, in[i])
            }
            esc = false
        default:
            res = append(res, in[i])
        }
    }
    return res,nil

}
```

[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/24A3F8Vv6q)

Comment: Thanks, this does look very extendable. I'll give it a try.